ExpressJs Session data not being saved in cookie
Yes, I know there's so many questions on this, but sadly, no answers that help me.
I am on Chrome, using ExpressJS, and VueJs 3. I have a basic application where I can "login" and it takes me to another page. Literally all I want to do is save the username in the session so I know who's logged in, but it doesn't save after the post request. It's gone next time I try to get the data. I know this is probably a cookie problem, but I'm not sure what else to try.
I've tried making sure they're on the same host, probably all cookie options available, with different hosts, saving the req in the post request as a promise. Nothing works.
index.js
require("dotenv").config();
var Express = require("express");
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { User, Note, Gift } = require("./models");
var cors = require("cors");

var app = Express();
app.use(Express.json());
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',  //Your Client, do not write '*'
    credentials: true,
};
app.use(cors());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret-key',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: false, sameSite: 'none', maxAge: 60000 }
  }));

var CONNECTION_STRING = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
var DATABASENAME="gifttracker";

app.listen(5038, () => {
    mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_STRING,{
        dbName: DATABASENAME,
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('Mongo DB Donnection Successful');
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error connecting to MongoDB: ', err)
    });
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const sessionData = req.session;
    console.log("get", sessionData);
    res.send(sessionData).status(200);
});


app.post('/api/createUser', async (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new User({ ...req.body });
    const createdUser = await newUser.save();
    console.log("createUser", createdUser);
    req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
    req.session.username = createdUser.username;
    req.session.save();
    res.send(req.session).status(200);
})

vue.config.js proxy so that both are on the same host
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: [
    'quasar'
  ],

  pluginOptions: {
    quasar: {
      importStrategy: 'kebab',
      rtlSupport: false
    }
  },
  devServer:{
    host: 'localhost',
    hot: true,
    port: 8080,
    proxy: { //https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#disable-index-generation
      '/api/': { //web sockets
        target: 'http://localhost:5038',
        secure: false,
        ws: true
      },
    }
  }
})

HelloWorld.vue - when I refresh this page, the get request should contain the session.username but doesn't
<template>
  <div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <div>
      <input v-model="form.name" required/>
      <input v-model="form.username" required/>
      <input v-model="form.password" type="password" required/>
      <input v-model="form.email"/>
      <input v-model="form.birthday"/>
      <button @click="addUser()">Create Account</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
const API_URL="http://localhost:8080/";
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        name: null,
        username: null,
        password: null,
        email: null,
        birthday: null
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async addUser() {
      console.log("USER: ", this.form);
      axios.post(API_URL+"api/createUser", this.form).then((user) => {
        console.log("user created", user);
        this.$router.push("Dashboard");
      }).catch((err)=> {
        console.log("err",err);
      })
      this.getSessionData();
    },
    async getSessionData() {
      axios.get(API_URL, {credentials: "include"}).then((res) => {
        console.log("res", res);
        if (res.username) {
          this.loggedIn = true;
          this.username = res.username;
        }
      })
    },
  }
}
</script>


perhaps use {credentials: "include"}  in all requests, so the cookie is sent in all requests?

@JaromandaX great suggestion, but it did not work. I think I will move forward with a client side version like this in the meantime. I'm sure it'll become more apparent as to what was wrong as I build my app. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-3-pinia-registration-login-example?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FNav.vue

When you receive a response from the server, I think you need to access the response data using res.data:
axios.get(API_URL, { withCredentials: true })
  .then((res) => {
    console.log("res", res);
    if (res.data.username) {
      this.loggedIn = true;
      this.username = res.data.username;
    }
  })

Also, try moving getSessionData inside the .then() block:
async addUser() {
      console.log("USER: ", this.form);
      axios.post(API_URL+"api/createUser", this.form).then((user) => {
        console.log("user created", user);
        this.getSessionData();
        this.$router.push("Dashboard");
      }).catch((err)=> {
        console.log("err",err);
      })
    }

I hope this helps!
